# Strange Vim inner borders

Tags: vim

I'm using gVIM with Windows 8, and since first time I opened it theres always those strange borders at right and bottom sides:

*normal window [[full size image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4qSX.jpg)*
[image: gVIM borders]

*fullscreen [[full size image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svi7N.jpg) - even bigger borders, look at the green dotted area at right and bottom*
[image: gVIM borders - fullscreen]

*restored*

[image: gVIM borders - restored]

Im using

```
set guioptions-=m
set guioptions-=t
set guioptions-=T
set guioptions-=r
set guioptions-=L
```

so no scrollbars and menus.

Any idea of how to remove those borders as in the left side?

---

Additional information: Tested in Windows XP with 1280x1024 in a 17" display.
And Windows 8 with 1920x1080 in a 21"5, same problem.

Comment: partial solution here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vim#Empty_space_at_the_bottom_of_gvim_windows

Comment: thanks puk, but doesnt work for me

Comment: Sorry, I see now that you are using windows. If I recall correctly, the problem has to do with gVim trying to best match the size up to column and line sizes, hence some space gets left over. This space is then filled up with whatever the window color is.

Comment: Have you checked [this related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47831/how-to-remove-gvims-fat-bottom-border-and-resize-grip)?

It worked for me.

Comment: It's great do know there are good solutions for linux users. My problem is with windows :/

Comment: You've shown us what options are not set, but can you type `:set go` and let us know what options are set? I'm trying to duplicate your issue (on Windows 7 though, but it's closer to Win XP than Linux). Also, what version of VIM (in case it makes a difference... I'm using 7.4).

Comment: @JasonDown Sure, `:set go` outputs: `guioptions=eg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows, using a different version of the fullscreen.dll solved this issue nicely.

https://github.com/xqin/gvimfullscreen

Answer (score 34):

I was able to fix this in Ubuntu 13.04 by creating `~/.gtkrc-2.0` with the following contents:

```
style "vimfix" {
  bg[NORMAL] = "#242424" # this matches my gvim theme 'Normal' bg color.
}
widget "vim-main-window.*GtkForm" style "vimfix"
```

Comment: Worked on Centos 6.4 without issues .

Comment: Worked on Arch Linux with Gnome 3.14.3

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Worked in Linux Mint 17.2

Comment: How to do this in GTK3?

Comment: This isn't actually a fix, it's more like a workaround. This will not make vim maximize to the window or to the screen, but will paint the unused area with a color similar to vim's bg. But this is the best we can do for now (about 5 years with this issue), every time I set up a new machine, I end up here and use the same old snnipet

Comment: Works fine for me Debian Jessie, I created a `.gtkrc-2.0.mine` because I already have a `.gtkrc-2.0`

Comment: Makes gvim in i3 look a lot better. Thank you!

Comment: For new versions of vim using gtk3, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39768273/695459).

Comment: Worked in Linux Mint 18

Answer (score 4):

I've enocuntered this problem as well, but never found a great solution. What worked for me was changing the font/font-size and possibly the windowmanager (on Linux).

```
:set guifont=*
```

**Update**: Switching to Neovim and nvim-qt solved this issue entirely for me!

Comment: There are two kind of gaps. The white one in the screenshots, which can be "improved" by setting a matching color as in the selected answer, and the other one which can be reduced playing with font size and space between lines (e.g. `:set linespace=5`).

Comment: Oh, didn't see this answer before I put mine in. This is what worked for me in the situation (on Windows 7).

Answer (score 4):

An old question, I know. I don't have a permanent solution, but I have figured out a good workaround:

1. Switch to an old-style Windows theme, one you can modify color-by-color. On my system, I have 'high-contrast black', which has the "right" settings without modification. Regardless, any old-style theme will work.
2. Those gVim "margins" pick up the color of the '3D Objects' parameter of the old-style theme. Set this parameter to whatever color you want the margins to be--I choose black.
3. Start gVim
4. Switch back to your usual Windows theme.

The margins will still be there, but they'll be black (or whatever color you choose), so they'll not only be less noticeable, they'll also let your eyes adjust to using gVim in a dark room with a dark, low-contrast theme. Of course, you'll have to do this every time you start gVim.

Comment: Thanks Shay, I could'nt really test it here because now I'm using Windows 8 and it gives me fewer color customization options. If worked here it would be a nice workaround, although today my brain already forgot about those borders there.

Comment: What does alt-shift-printscreen do on Windows 8? This will switch to high-contrast on Windows 7 and down. Starting gVim on high contrast will get black margins. I cannot ignore them when trying to work in a dark room--those margins put out a lot of light.

Comment: It doest turns on high contrast, but I could'nt find where to configure the color used for those borders, there's no '3D objects' configuration also.

Comment: Thank you for trying that out. Guess I'll have to dig deeper when I upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you can remove this border. I have all the gui elements turned off for gVim like you and i get the same border, only mine is slightly bigger when being maximised on a larger screen.

I would imagine it's rounding the display size to nearest whole character block.

Comment: Although I agree that there appears no way to fix it, it seems strange that the terminal gets this right but gVim does not

Answer (score 1):

This plugin solved the grey inner border in fullscreen mode:
https://github.com/derekmcloughlin/gvimfullscreen_win32

Looks like a minor change to the code would allow the same fix (black color instead of grey) in windowed mode.

I really recommend this plug, it makes gvim in windows worth using for me!

Comment: How did this plugin solve the problem for you? I use this plugin and yet get those borders, from second image.

Comment: There is an older version of that plugin somewhere on the internet that does cause grey borders in fullscreen, maybe you are using that version? Try building the latest version from source from the github link.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by your guioptions.
I can reliably reproduce this issue on Windows 7 when setting guioptions on one single line.

I fixed it by setting the following guioptions individually (each option on a new line):

```
set guioptions-=T "remove toolbar
set guioptions-=r "remove right-hand scroll bar
set guioptions-=L "remove left-hand scroll bar. Fix for TagBar.
```

Comment: Thanks Jean, but in my vimrc I already do as you pointed, didn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

I was having this problem using gvim in a urxvt.

Changing the urxvt internalBorder to 0 resolve this for me.