# Vim how to remove white edges

Tags: vim

When I open vim I'm getting vim but with white edges. If you don't see this in image - just open this image in new TAB[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: by any chance your terminal background is white?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove white border in gVim 8 with gtk 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763539/how-to-remove-white-border-in-gvim-8-with-gtk-3)

Comment: @nbari, yes But how can I make terminal color and vim same? Now I've color in vim: gruvbox.